# hash() returning different values on different OSs

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, python-internals

When python builtin `hash()` is just wired cross-platform. I have an app use builtin `hash()` for `'test'`. Both systems are 64bit, python 2.7.12

windows:

```
>>> hash('test')
1308370872
```

linux:

```
>>> hash('test')
2314058222102390712
```

Why is this?

Comment: when use hashlib, everything is fine. Is there any doc refered to this difference?

Comment: Do you expect them to return the same values? Why? Running `hash("test")` twice in different sessions on the same system, returns different values each time.

Comment: Maybe one python is 32bit and another is 64bit? You can run python 32bit on a 64bit operating system

Comment: @donkopotamus nope

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned that they are using Python 2.7.12. So the dupe is not relevant, as it is about Python 3.3. Reopening the question.

Comment: I can't image all of you disccus so much, as I completely know nothing about the build_in function. True that hashlib solve my problem: I need the same strings return the same num squence. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no guarantees about the value `hash` returns in Python.  It appears that you're using a 32-bit Windows Python (that's a guess), and that you're using a 64-bit python on linux (again, a guess).  IIRC (and I haven't checked), The default `hash(item)` returns the address of `item` as its hash value.

If you want to have values you can compare across operating systems, look at [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/hashlib.html?highlight=hashlib).

Comment: I just reread the question; `hash(item)` returning the address of `item` could return wildly different values betweens different runs on one platform, much less on different ones, regardless of 32/64-bit issues.

Comment: Worse, two strings with equal value don't necessarily have the same memory address, but they need to have the same hash or they could appear twice in dictionary keys. So this can't be it.

Comment: Yep.  Python does us a lot of favors by interning strings transparently, so `hash('foo')` could be either the same or different from `xx='foo'; hash(xx)`.  `hashlib` has solutions for this problem.

Comment: hashlib is completely immune to the "problem" as it simply doesn't care about the address, the hash depends on the string's value. Same for hash().

Comment: True, but hash() isn't guaranteed to be platform-independent, and hashlib is.